# OpenLayers - clear 'map' div

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers to display dynamically loaded images. The code I am using is:

```
      var map;
      function init(strURL) {
      map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');

      var options = { numZoomLevels: 3,
                isBaseLayer: true, };

      var graphic = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image(
            'City Lights',
            strURL + "?sc=page",
            new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180, -88.759, 180, 88.759),
            new OpenLayers.Size(580, 288),
            options
        );

    //    graphic.events.on({
    //      loadstart: function () {
    //        OpenLayers.Console.log("loadstart");
    //      },
    //      loadend: function () {
    //        OpenLayers.Console.log("loadend");
    //      }
    //    });

    var jpl_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("NASA Global Mosaic",
            "http://t1.hypercube.telascience.org/cgi-bin/landsat7",
            { layers: "landsat7" }, options);

    map.addLayers([graphic, jpl_wms]);


    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();

  }
```

I am calling this function on a button click event and passing the strURL (sources of the images) at that time. The result is, with each click a different image is loaded and displayed on the web page but is not clearing the previous image. So I 5 different images on the webpage are shown with 5 clicks and so on.

My javascript knowledge is limited, so my apologies if this is a stupid question. How to stop this behavior? Thanks for any assistance.

Also, I didn't quite understand the lines:

```
    var jpl_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("NASA Global Mosaic",
        "http://t1.hypercube.telascience.org/cgi-bin/landsat7",
        { layers: "landsat7" }, options);
```

But I know these lines are needed since I'm getting js error if I remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So currently you are calling init(strURL) with each button click? Divide that code into two parts:

- On page load, create map and layer objects
- On button click, just update URL of existing image layer. Image layer has setUrl(url) method for that: http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Image-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Image.setUrl

Here is sample, that should explain it: http://jsfiddle.net/mEHrN/6/

About var jpl_wms = ... - it creates WMS layer, that should display Landsat imagery (but that URL doesn't seem to work). If you remove it, remember also to remove it from map.addLayers:

```
map.addLayers([graphic]);
```

Probably this was reason, why you got JS error.

Comment: I had solved the problem by clearing the html of the map div on each click but your solution is more elegant. Thanks for taking the time to answer it and creating the fiddle.